# Rewrite WordPress Custom URL

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect, htaccess

I have a custom WordPress url which is generated by **ID**. I have to rewrite this url `https://example.com/account/customer-bookings/?view-booking=4` to `https://example.com/account/customer-bookings/view-booking/4`. How Can I don it?

My Current .htaccess code is following,

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php56” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: first you need to find the real URL without rewriting of `account/customer-bookings/?view-booking=4`. it must be something like `index.php?view-booking=4`. edit your question to add this information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WordPress has its own system managing redirects and page routes, you don't need to edit the .htaccess file. You'll want to start with the function [`add_rewrite_rule()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/).

It takes 3 arguments:

1. route (as regex)
2. query vars
3. priority

So first, you need to find out the query vars of `account/customer-bookings/`. If it is a page, it can be `page_id`. To reproduce what WordPress already does, it could be (XXX being the specific page_id):

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^account/customer-bookings/?$',
    'index.php?page_id=XXX'
);
```

---

Now you just need to expand this: (**don't forget to flush rewrite rules after adding this code!**)

```
add_action('init', 'wpse_view_booking_rewrite');
function wpse_view_booking_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^account/customer-bookings/view-booking/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?page_id=XXX&view-booking=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
```

This should already present the correct page. However, you won't be able to use `get_query_var('view-booking')`, because it is no default variable. To solve this, simply tell WP to watch out for it like so

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'wpse_view_bookings_filter');
function wpse_view_bookings_filter($vars) {
    $vars[] = 'view-booking';
    return $vars;
}
```

At this point WordPress knows about the variable, and by calling `get_query_var('view-booking')` you will get the proper variable.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm little bit confused about `page_id=XXX`. Also the placement area of your codes. Let me describe about that page I'm talking, First I have create page from the WordPress backend page menu id with 221. Then I have create a template from the WordPress theme directory. And make some custom WordPress query using $wpdb.

Comment: You can place this code in your theme's functions.php for it to work. You say the created page has the ID 221 (you see it in the URL when editing in the backend), so replace `XXX` by `221` making it `'index.php?page_id=221&view-booking=$matches[1]',`. Now in the page template, use `$booking = get_query_var('view-booking');` and you can use `$booking` when constructing the WP Query.

Comment: I have use following codes into `function.php` but, it's not working. Please find the following url http://prntscr.com/kjs3vy, http://prntscr.com/kjs4j9

Comment: @SonjoyDatta The first code was only an example, please delete lines 291-294 in the first screenshot

Comment: I have remove lines 291-294. Then flush rewrite rules but, still same problem. http://prntscr.com/kjsavk, http://prntscr.com/kjsb4s, http://prntscr.com/kjsbkm

Comment: The link needs to be of the format `account/customer-bookings/view-booking/4` (in the `href=".."`), not `?view-booking=..`